# Bootstrap menu disappears on click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with menu on website wrapster.sebastianbialek.pl. When we resize a browser to mobile version and click on collapse button menu will show up for a few second then disappears. Can anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Regards,
Sebastian

Comment: could you provide your code. or link where  i can check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is not defined.

Just add jQuery ubove the comment - Revolution Slider in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I have jquery above  Revolution Slider, below Base JS comment

Comment: Oh yes, you do now :)

Comment: I am trying to figure it out

Comment: Try adding .collapse.in { display: block !important; } in your css

Comment: the problem is that you have .navbar-collapse.collapse as important too. This is where things get tangled

Comment: Okey, when i delete a !important from .navbar-collapse.collapse  and add your line od code menu work fine but when resize browser above 767 menu glitched. I need to show menu without that collapse button.

Comment: You could apply the mobile menu styles to the CSS media query 991px.

Comment: Okey i will. Thanks for your help!